# Debug automatic laptop shutdown problem

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and recently it started getting shutdown automatically while I am using it. I am sure there is no problem with any part getting over heating. Some times it happens 5 mins after booting and some times after hours. I think I am having this problem after some kernel update.

I am clueless how to debug this problem. Can anyone tell me which logs I can check to find out the potential issue.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm running 10.04, and this has now happened twice in the past couple of weeks. A proper, graceful, shutdown. Each time when I had my back turned; I look back and it is shutting down. Like you I don't think it is overheating (that one is like someone pulled the plug, not at all graceful), and I don't know how to debug it. None of syslog, kern.log or messages have anything at the time of shutdown except one line: "kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped."

Comment: Mine is not graceful shutdown :( It's getting completely turned off. Mostly I am facing when I am running the Skype. Still no clue whey this is happening

Comment: Sudden shutdowns are usually overheating; cleaning out the dust can help. Or some electrical problem (e.g. if your laptop is getting old).    (My graceful shutdown problem went away, so I've no idea why!)